# Wanting scanf to proceed without all parameters filled

Tags: c

I want to have a scanf function that allows the user to input up to four integers separated by spaces but still run if only 2 integers are put in.

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &command, &num_one, &num_two, &num_three);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`scanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) does exactly that. It returns the number of successful conversions it performed. If it cannot perform a conversion (or cannot match a literal character), it stops reading precisely at that point.

You should always check its return value, even if the examples you are copying don't do that.

What `scanf` doesn't guarantee is that the values converted are separated by spaces. They might be separated by newlines. If you want a newline character to stop the scan, you need to read the line using something like [`fgets`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) (or, better if possible, the Posix [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) function), and then call `sscanf` on the line which was read.

You could also force `scanf` to stop at the end of the line by using `%*[ \t]` instead of to separate the `%d`s, which will only match space and tab characters. (The `*` causes `scanf` to not try to save the matched string, and also to not count the conversion in its return count.) But that will run you into the other problem with `scanf`: if there is garbage in the line, you normally want to continue reading with the next line. The `getline/sscanf` solution will do that for you. If you use `scanf`, you'll need to manually flush the rest of the input line, which requires calling `fgets` or `getline` anyway.

And  while I'm at it, note that there is no difference between `scanf("%d %d %d %d", ...)` and `scanf("%d%d%d%d", ...)`, because `%d`, like all scanf conversions other than `%c`, `%[` and `%%`, skips leading whitespace.

Comment: The problem is that if i only enter 2 integers it doesn't proceed until I enter another 2.

Comment: @Isaac: That's the issue with it accepting newlines as whitespace.